# Swiper doesn't work with draggable content using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, swiper.js

When I use swiper in Javascripts it works will but when I update one slide with content and make it draggable using JQuery .the content cann't be draggable why?
Here 's my code

```
    <!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <style>
                #draggable {
                    width: 150px;
                    height: 150px;
                    padding: 0.5em;
                }
            </style>
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $("#draggable").draggable();
                });
            </script>
            <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
                <p>Drag me around</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>

<!-- Swiper JS -->
<!--<script src="../dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="swiper.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="swiper.js"></script>
<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        paginationClickable: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'd flip a guess being because both actions are utilizing `draggable`. How does the application know which you're intending to use? Drag to Swipe? Or drag the `div` around? Think about it.

Comment: okay what is the trick to overlap this problem???